# CLISP representation of a list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am experimenting with using `substitute-if`. Here I try to replace all values that are even in `'((1) (2) (3) (4))` with `'(0)`

```
[9]> (substitute-if '(0) #'evenp '((1) (2) (3) (4)) :start 1 :key #'car)
((1) #1=(0) (3) #1#)
```

I am confused about the `#1=(0)` and `#1` in the list. I expected it to return `'((1) (0) (3) (0))`.

Am I misunderstanding how `substitute-if` works or misunderstanding the representation of the list?

Comment: [Variable ``*PRINT-CIRCLE*``](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/v_pr_cir.htm), FYI.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Am I misunderstanding how `substitute-if` works or misunderstanding the representation of the list?

Probably the latter.

`#1=...` marks a spot in the data structure and `#1#` refers back to it. The idea is to show that both elements refer to the same list. (See also http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_dhp.htm.)

It's like:

```
(let ((x '(0)))
  (list '(1) x '(3) x))
```

Because they refer to the same object, if you were to modify the second list in place, the modification would also show up in the fourth list.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you have set the dynamic global variable [`*print-circle*`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/v_pr_cir.htm) to something truthy. If you evaluate `*print-circle*` you'll see it.

```
; make a list (1 1 1 1 1 ...)
(defparameter *test* (list 1))
(setf (cdr *test*) *test*)

(setf *print-circle* t)
(substitute-if '(0) #'evenp '((1) (2) (3) (4)) :start 1 :key #'car)
; ==> ((1) #1=(0) (3) #1#)
*test*
; ==> #1=(1 . #1#)

(setf *print-circle* nil)
(substitute-if '(0) #'evenp '((1) (2) (3) (4)) :start 1 :key #'car)
; ==> ((1) (0) (3) (0))
*test* ; never finishes
```

The last one will hang until it runs out of memory. be hurry to cancel it out or your system will surely be sluggish once it has used all your available memory and buffers and start getting the system to swap out other things.

This is why we have `*print-circle*`. The ability to see lists that are circular. The printed data structure is always the same so it's only how it is displayed which is different.

When you use `substitute-if` and replace with `'(0)` this has one address in memory and thus when `*print-circle*` is truthy it will only print it once and the other references will be shown as references since the system looks for the same object and not if it really is circular or not.